# WinForm ComboBox Drawing Bug

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForm with TableLayoutPanel and ComboBoxes inside. Combo boxes expand by percantage size. And always after start application, left combobox has artifacts like these:
[image: combobox artifacts]

but the disappear as soon as I put a mouse on them. I have already tried different options, and the only thing that helps, is to set a constant size for all comboboxes, but that's not good for me.

That's how sizes looks like:

[image: sizes]

And how looks like typical scheme of my form:

[image: schema]

- Red squares - TableLayoutPanel with content;
- Green squares - TableLayoutPanel without content, with margin 0, and single border.

Maybe somebody has ideas on how to fix this bug? Thanks.

Comment: It is a glitch in the visual styles renderer, specific to your Windows version.  You have to mention it, I'd guess at Win7 judging from the style and the frequency of bugs in its renderers.  Belongs to a class of bugs, ComboBox is [not fond of getting resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151447/odd-combobox-behavior-on-resize/2151679#2151679) after it is created.  Tinkering with its Visible property might be a viable approach.  Trying to bypass it is not the best idea, you'd have to make sure that a workaround still works okay in a later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's really a bug, but I found a simple solution.
Just subscribe to SizeChanged Event of parrent control/form and call Refresh() method in event handler. Control will be redrawn to the required size.

[image]

Comment: Is your combobox docked inside TLP column? I think I have similar problem

Comment: @pitersmx yes. My solution did not help you?