# the Focus event on Combo box is generated twice. Win Desktop API

Tags: c++, winapi

The focus event on the combo box is generated twice.
this is the code for the Action Procedure of the Dialog box.

```
INT_PTR DialogBox::ActionProc(
    HWND hwndDlg,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
        {
        case WM_COMMAND:
                {
                    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                        {
                            case COMBOBOX:
                            {
                                if (CBN_SETFOCUS == HIWORD(wParam))
                                {
                                    MessageBox(
                                    hwndDlg,
                                    CString("Test"),
                                    CString("Test"),
                                    (MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK));
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                                default:
                                    break;
                        }
                    break;
                }
        default:
            break;
        }
    return INT_PTR(true);    
}
```

the MessageBox Gets displayed twice(because the focus event is generated twice on the combo box). Is there a way to display it only once.

I have tried focussing to another element such as:

```
INT_PTR DialogBox::ActionProc(
    HWND hwndDlg,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
        {
        case WM_COMMAND:
                {
                    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                        {
                            case COMBOBOX:
                            {
                                if (CBN_SETFOCUS == HIWORD(wParam))
                                {
                                    MessageBox(
                                    hwndDlg,
                                    CString("Test"),
                                    CString("Test"),
                                    (MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK));
                                    SendDlgItemMessage(
                                    hwndDlg,
                                    ANOTHER_CONTROL,
                                    WM_SETFOCUS,
                                    0,
                                    0);

                                }
                                break;
                            }
                                default:
                                    break;
                        }
                    break;
                }
        default:
            break;
        }
    return INT_PTR(true);    
}
```

Can some one tell me what i am doing wrong.

This is in Windows Desktop API.

Comment: at begin not use `MessageBox` which affect focus. use `DbgPrint` or some another log instead

Comment: Also, don't send `WM_SETFOCUS`. It is a notification message send by the system and not intended to be send by applications. The correct way to set focus in a dialog is to send the `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message as explained by Raymond Chen in his article [How to set focus in a dialog box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283/).

Comment: The question is pretty misleading, everybody will latch on to using MessageBox being a rather bad idea to debug focusing notifications.  But yes, there is a wonky issue with combobox, it mistakenly generates a focusing notification when its size changes after it is created.  Most visible side-effect is that it shows the current selection highlighted in blue, even when the control doesn't have the focus.   More about that glitch in [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151447/odd-combobox-behavior-on-resize).